# Python Selenium - NoSuchElementException. Why do I keep getting this?

Tags: python, selenium, paste

I am trying to paste values into a form using Selenium in Python, but I keep getting `NoSuchElementException` as shown in the picture below.

I tried various `find_element_by_xx` but keep getting the same error.
Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

The form I'm filling in is a custom querying Cognos report. The ID is visible of the block (shown in the pic below), but it does not seem to be working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("website") #"website" is placeholder
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("PRMT_TB_N0000000016B521C0x000000002552DDD8_NS_")
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
```

**Form**:

[image: Form Id]

**Code:**

[image: Code]

**Exception:**

[image: Exception]

Comment: The id in your question does not match the id of the element in your first picture

Comment: @IainShelvington. Thank you for pointing out. I have made them match.
The ID i had in code, originally, was ID of the second form.
I have corrected code to match image. It returns same error :(

Comment: Is it possible for you to link the website?

Comment: I figured it out! I copied "Full Xpath" and used the find_element_by_expath.
Normal xPath did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Copy Full Xpath when inspecting the element and use find_element_by_xpath.